# Old Norse kné: a- stem or wa- stem?

Tags: germanic-languages, old-norse, declension, stems

The neuter noun *kné* follows *a*-stem declension.

But it comes from Proto-Germanic **knewą*. This seems to be a *wa*-stem.

Then why does it follow *a*-stem declension? Did Scandinavians force it to, even though it was *wa*-stem noun?